# iPad app - generating text file

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Can someone explain and give example code to do the following steps in my iPad app:

1. do some things in my app, which generates some data (as a string)
2. write that data to a text file
3. be able to plug in my iPad to my computer and grab those text files off

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For writing string in a file use this

```
NSString *str = @"your string";
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
NSError *error;
[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Then set `Application supports iTunes file sharing` key to `YES` in your plist file.

When you connect your device with iTunes from there you can save your `data.txt`
[Here is the video how to get files from iTunes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ-LcjC7Zww)

---

**Edited** as requested.

```
NSUserDefaults *deflt = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//this number file is saved, I'm not saving the file name as data0.txt.
//The first file to be saved is data1.txt
int num = [deflt integerForKey:@"fileNameNum"]; 
num++;
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data%d.txt",num];;
NSString *str = @"your string";
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSError *error = nil;
[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    //Save the number of the file that you have save in doc directory
    [deflt setInteger:num forKey:@"fileNameNum"];
}
```

Comment: @StanLe.. I have already edited my answer and added a video link to show how to get files from iTunes. I know this that you will get this problem :)

Comment: awesome. works great. now...one other thing. let's say I have a folder in my app called "Data" and in that folder, it basically saves a text file DataFileX.txt (where X is an integer, starting from 1) each time the app is used. how can I figure out the next name to use. For example, if I just saved to Data/DataFile12.txt, then I should next save to Data/DataFile13.txt. Can you update your code to reflect this? THANKS!!

Comment: hey edited again...changed the if(error!=nil) to if(error==nil)